# Получить ExitCode приложения на удаленном компьютере

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста:

В C# новичок, строго прошу не судить.

**Суть вопроса**:

Написал программу-родителя, в которой по нажатию на кнопку на удаленном компьютере запускает дочернее консольное приложение.

Мне необходимо получить ExitCode дочернего приложения и вернуть в программу-родитель и записать в ТехtBox значение ExitCode.

Порождение процесса на удаленном ПК в программе-родителе:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Username = Form1.user;
    string Password = Form1.password;

    ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions(); 
    connection.Username = Form1.user;
    connection.Password = Form1.password;
    connection.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate; 
    connection.EnablePrivileges = true;

    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + ip + @"\root\CIMV2", connection);

    scope.Connect();

    ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
    ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
    ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(scope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);

    ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
    inParams["CommandLine"] = @"app.exe";
    //inParams["ProcessStartupInformation"] = "";       
    ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
}
```

В дочернем приложении:

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("D:\\TestFile.txt");
file.Write("test");
file.Close();
if (File.Exists(@"D:\\TestFile.txt") == true)
{
    Environment.ExitCode = SUCESS; //возвращает 0
}
else
{
    Environment.ExitCode = ERROR_BAD; //возвращает 1
}
```

Пробовал так:

```
ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
string retVal = outParams["ReturnValue"].ToString();
textBox2.Text += (retVal).ToString() + "\r\n";
```

Но мне возвращает всего лишь результат выполнение запуска приложения на удаленном компьютере, а мне необходимо получить результат работы дочернего консольного приложения и записать в TextBox.

Заранее большое спасибо всем откликнувшимся.

---

**Дополнение**:

Попробовал совет (ссылка) в комментарии, не смог разобраться.

Кто может подсказать как получить код завершения консольного приложения на удаленном компьютере, зная proccesId и имя запущенного процесса?

Если есть примеры буду благодарен.

Comment: ExitCode начинает действовать по завершению работы процесса, который установил ExitCode. Поэтому нужно сделать завершение процесса после `Environment.ExitCode`

Comment: Понятно что вас такой расклад дел не устроит, на это ответ - нужно использовать другие пути обмена между процессами. Из того-же блюда - можете передавать Priority.  И ещё момент - нужно ждать, ведь процесс может запускаться и 10 секунд. А вы и одну секунду не ждете. Нужно, например раз в секунду спрашивать "статус" напротяжении там... минуты хотя бы.

Comment: nick_n_a по поводу отпроса статуса, могли бы чуть подробнее объяснить. Процесс прерывается как раз на Environment.ExitCode. или нужно еще добавить завершение? Если да, то как мне его увидеть программой-родителем?

Comment: [тыц](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/padmanr/2010/05/08/execute-a-process-on-remote-machine-wait-for-it-to-exit-and-retrieve-its-exit-code-using-wmi/)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, буду пробовать, думаю это то, что мне нужно. Попрошу Вас, добавить это как ответ.

Comment: Ссылка в качестве ответа не годится. А писать полноценное сообщение я не готов. Напишите ответ сами (и примите потом).